# Pi-hole Admin Interface doesn't load with http://<ip-addr>/admin

Tags: networking, server, apache2

I've Installed Pi-hole on my ubuntu 22.04 server

When I go to https:///admin, there should be an Interface.
But it return **404 Not Found**!

Debug token generated by **pihole -d** returns the following on Red:

```
[✗] tcp:*:80 is in use by apache2 (https://docs.pi-hole.net/main/prerequisites/#ports)

*** [ DIAGNOSING ]: Pi-hole processes
[✗] lighttpd daemon is failed
[✓] pihole-FTL daemon is active


*** [ DIAGNOSING ]: Dashboard headers
[✗] Web interface X-Header: X-Header does not match or could not be retrieved.
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Wed, 25 Jan 2023 21:19:43 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: You installed both Apache2 and  Pi-hole. Pi-hole contains `lighttpd` as a dedicated web server. Both try to listen on port 80. Either remove Apache2, or configure Pi-hole to listen on a different port.